# onAccessibilityEvent is not called

Tags: android, android-studio

```
public class TestService extends AccessibilityService {
String text;
Context context;
TestService(String text,Context context){
    this.text=text;enter code here
    this.context=context;

}
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"helo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
        if (source != null && event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED && event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText")) {
            android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

I have used it to copy and paste my clipboard text to wherever my current text cursor is focused but it is not working? I am kind of newbie to this accessibility service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, look on this [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService). But the problem is that Google some time ago changed policy and now Accessibility Service can be used only for assist users with disabilities.